# What is the fraction of the time that the JWST could view a short transient event on-demand as a function of position on the celestial sphere?

Tags: observational-astronomy, time-domain-astronomy, james-webb-space-telescope

In [this answer to *Why does JWST have such a big Blind Spot?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56077/12102) I argue that this space telescope primary relationship with time is that it strives to look way back in it and so as long as a given direction is visible sometime during the year and it doesn't matter that at any moment only about 40% of $4 \pi$ SR is viewable (polar angles 85° to 135° wrt the Sun, see below).

But now I'm wondering

1. If there are some types of transient events where an infrared telescope like this (0.6 to 28 microns I think?) could offer something that Hubble or ground observatories couldn't. For that I've already asked [For what types of transient events would the JWST be ideal or even uniquely-suited for observing? (If it could look in time)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47726/7982)

But here I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What is the fraction of the time that the JWST could view a short transient event on-demand as a function of position on the celestial sphere?"

The author of that question gives a few examples just to illustrate the idea of transient events

> Over a 6 month half-orbit of the sun, the entire sky is observable. But what happens if an interesting event occurs in the “blind spot”? Like Shoemaker-Levy or the arrival of Rama? A gravitational wave event?

and (at least) one of those really did "shine" in the thermal infrared!

---

**JWST's field of regard (FOR)** from the linked question and originally from [JWST field of regard (FOR)](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard#JWSTObservatoryCoordinateSystemandFieldofRegard-forJWSTfieldofregard(FOR)) Also see [How much of the sky can the JWST see?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14551/12102).

[image: JWST's field of regard (FOR)]

Comment: Note the timescale for Target of Opportunity (ToO) observations for both HST and JWST are long for a substantial fraction of transient science. Non disruptive ToOs, which already require significant additional justification in the proposal, take at least 2 weeks before execution. Disruptive ToOs, of which there can only be 8 triggers per cycle, take 48 hours (Source: [JWST ToO restrictions](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-opportunities-and-policies/jwst-call-for-proposals-for-cycle-1/jwst-cycle-1-observation-types-and-restrictions/target-of-opportunity-observations))

Comment: Space Telescope Science Institute video [Webb's Field of Regard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0bOi3kVIBs)

Comment: @astrosnapper That link is now dead. But there's general ToO info on https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/methods-and-roadmaps/jwst-target-of-opportunity-observations

Comment: There's now a new [link](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-opportunities-and-policies/jwst-call-for-proposals-for-cycle-2/jwst-observation-types#JWSTObservationTypes-TOOobservationsTarget-of-Opportunity(ToO)Observations) for Cycle 2 but your link looks to be the better and more general/stable one @PM2Ring

Answer (score 1):

Depends largely on the targets elevation/altitude/latitude above the solar ecliptic.

Best case is for targets that are within 5° of the poles of the solar ecliptic. These targets never leave the Field of Regard for JWST.

> JWST operates in an ecliptic coordinate framework, there are 2 small continuous viewing zones (CVZs) centered at each of the ecliptic poles (see Figure 6). The 85° solar exclusion zone then determines the radius of the allowed CVZs to be essentially 5°, although any observation approaching the 85° limit will have additional limitations due to safety considerations. [1](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard#JWSTObservatoryCoordinateSystemandFieldofRegard-CVZContinuousviewingzone(CVZ))

Blind time increases for targets farther from the poles of the solar ecliptic.

Worst case is for targets that are directly on the solar ecliptic.

```
Field of Regard "Width": 50° (135° - 85°)
Field of Regard period: 1 sidereal year
```

The target will pass through the Field of Regard twice in a given period.

[50° / 360° * 1 sidereal year](https://www.google.com/search?q=50%2F360%20*%201%20sidereal%20year) = 50.7300504 days

By Angle:

```
 In:  50°
Out:  90° anti-solar blind spot
 In:  50°
Out: 170° sun shield blind spot
Repeat...
```

By Time:

```
 In:  50.7300504 days
Out:  91.3140908 days anti-solar blind spot
 In:  50.7300504 days
Out: 172.482171  days sun shield blind spot
Repeat...
```

I guess this isn't the precise function you are asking for, but maybe it provides someone else insights to discover the function. If I manage to do it I will update this answer.

Update: Here is a plot of said function against ecliptic latitude.
[image: Graph of the function against ecliptic latitude]

Comment: I just realized that JWST is in the ecliptic coordinate system and not in the equatorial coordinate system like all other telescopes. I suppose astronomers are already used to translating between all the astronomical coordinate systems.